# How can i append the name of my image as text inside my div as it preloads with my preloader function

Tags: jquery, image, append, preloader, preload

I have a javascript preloader that loads in an array of images to my page and then does a callback function after its finished.

During that preload I want to append the current image being preloaded to the HTML page in a loading box.  Here is my current code.  The current code doesn't work for each image but instead just displays the name of the last image loaded.  What can I do to fix my preloader function so that during each loop it appends the correct name to my div?

```
    // Usage: $(['img1.jpg','img2.jpg']).preloadImages(function(){ ... });
// Callback function gets called after all images are preloaded
$.fn.preloadImages = function(callback) {

  checklist = this.toArray();

  this.each(function() {
    $('div.circleText').html('<p>' +  this + '</p>');

    $('<img>').attr({ src: this }).load(function() {

      checklist.remove($(this).attr('src'));
      if (checklist.length == 0) { callback(); }
    });
  });
};

$([

'../img/about/01-inner-small.png',
'../img/about/01-small.png',
'../img/about/blue-gear.png',
'../img/about/orange-gear.png',
'../img/about/slimeGoblin.png',
'../img/about/03-small.png',
'../img/about/slideshow_back.png',
'../img/about/services_octopus.png',
'../img/about/services_pinkblur.png',
'../img/about/services_blur.png',
'../img/about/services_seahorse.png',
'../img/about/services_coral.png',
'../img/about/water3.png',
'../img/about/water2.png',
'../img/about/water1.png',
'../img/about/02-inner.png',
'../img/about/slime-glow.png',
'../img/about/02_longPhoto.png',
'../img/about/photo1.jpg',
'../img/about/orange-gear.png',
'../img/about/blue-gear.png',
'../img/about/01-small.png',
'../img/about/01.png',
'../img/about/slime-transparent.png',
'../img/about/slime.png',
'../img/about/02-small.png',
'../img/about/02.png',
'../img/about/01_head.png',
'../img/about/services_squid.png',
'../img/about/services_crabs.png',
'../img/about/02-small.png'

]).preloadImages(function(){ 
    // $('#loading').transition({ opacity: 0 }, 1000,'in-out',      
    //  function()
    //  { 
    //      $('#loading').hide();
    //  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution doesn't solve the problem, just the display.

The correct answer is here : http://jsfiddle.net/ES8kw/1/

The `.load()` function wasn't good.

```
.load(function() {
                delete checklist[$.inArray($(this).attr('src'),checklist)];
                $('#loading').html('<p>' + $(this).attr('src') + '</p>');
                var done = 0;
                $.each(checklist,function(i){ if(typeof checklist[i] == "undefined") { done++; }})
                if (checklist.length == done) {
                  callback();
              }
          });
```

And all of that needed to be wrapped in a `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, you just don't realize it because of how fast it occurs.  Replace the following line:

```
$('div.circleText').html('<p>' + value + '</p>');
```

With this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.circleText').html('<p>' + value + '</p>');
}, 1000 + (index * 100));
```

This will ensure that you see each of the array objects as the array is processed.  You can of course adjust the time each is visible for for however long you wish.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xHe7E/)

Comment: This solved the display issues so it answered my question, but the post from Elyx0 actually solved the concept of displaying the text and loading it during display.  SO you both answered correctly, but his answer is better code for my project so i scrapped my current loader!  thanks for your help!